# Failed to re-package resources from android studio to unity

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, arr

I need to use some .jar. So I use Android Studio to creat an empty application project. Then I have built the project. And copy the .arr and the AndroidManifest.xml to the Unity's /Plugins/Android. But when I bulit the apk in the unity, something goes wrong.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "D:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.example.lizhi.last_try -S "C:\Users\lizhi\Documents\Unity\Homony\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\app-debug\res"
```

I have deleted the classes.jar from the .arr. So it may not its problem.
And I have alerady put the in the  into AndroidManifest.xml.
So please help me. How could I fix this error. It drives me crasy.

Answer (score 0):

Yap, I had delt with that. It's just beacuse the Android Studio's JDK doesn't match with the unity's. Just change the unity's JDK. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If the above suggestion failed and you are still looking for a fix, go into your build tools directory of Android studio, cut + paste the 24.0.0 tools to your desktop or something and try it again, worked for me. I guess the 24 build tools aren't functioning with Unity